# Query en VBA me devuelve cuadrados blancos en vez de caracteres extranjeros

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba, db2

He intentado sacar datos de una base de datos a través de VBA en Excel, y en vez de caracteres extranjeros(chino, ruso, etc), me devuelve "???" o cuadrados blancos

**Código que uso:**

```
Option Explicit

Public conn As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public query As String
Public result As Variant
Public hostname As String
Public username As String
Public password As String
Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet

Sub setConn()
       
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 200
    conn.CommandTimeout = 200

    hostname = "hostname"
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    
    query = "SELECT * FROM SHPMODEDSC where LANGUAGE_ID in (-20) with ur;"
    
    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
        conn.Close
    End If
    
    conn.Open "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1};Database="database";Hostname=" & hostname & ";CurrentSchema="schema";Port=50000;Protocol=TCPIP;UID=" & username & ";PWD=" & password & ";"
    rs.Open query, conn
    
    result = rs.GetRows()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 2
    
    If Not IsEmpty(result) Then
    
        For i = 0 To UBound(result, 2)
            ws.Cells(j, 1).Value = result(0, i)
            ws.Cells(j, 2).Value = result(1, i)
            ws.Cells(j, 3).Value = result(2, i)
            j = j + 1
        Next i
        
        result = Empty
    End If
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

**Devuelve esto:**

[image: Result query]

[image: Result query]

Quiero poner los resultados en excel, tal que así:

[image: Results in excel]

He visto en otros foros/preguntas que aunque no se vean los caracteres en VBA se puede trabajar con ellos igualmente pero como se ve arriba, en excel siguen sin verse bien.

- **Database: IBM DB2**
- **Driver: IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER**

He intentado activar esta opción en W10:

[image: W10 utf-8 beta]

Pero si la activo el VBA crashea y me borra el código.

También he probado a usar las funciones StrConv y ChrW.

**Entiendo que el problema es en VBA porque si ejecuto la query en el Squirrel los datos salen bien.**

Cualquier idea de porqué pasa esto es bienvenida, gracias.

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Si haces un [CopyFromRecordset](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset) te sale igual? Tiene más pinta de problemas con la codificación que en sí con el código... Quizás otra opción sea hacerlo en 2 pasos: generar un txt recodificado correctamente para admitir los carácteres extranjeros y luego eso importarlo a Excel

Comment: @Esei La primera opción CopyFromRecordset no ha funcionado, pero muchas gracias igualmente, probaré generando un txt y luego importarlo